# ramda.js how to do the groupby, count, sort

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I hava a data collection like:

```
[{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":3,"score":4},{"id":1,"score":3}]
```

I want the ouput like :

```
[{"id":1,"count":3},{"id":2,"count":2},{"id":3,"count":1}]
```

Is there any solution to use Ramda.js to do this?

I tried to use `countBy(prop("id"))`, but i can not figure out the way of doing sort by count number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function with R.pipe, that uses R.countBy to get an object of `{ [id]: count }`, then converts the data to pairs, and generate an array of objects with R.map, and R.applySpec. Then sort it with R.sortBy.

```js
const { pipe, countBy, prop, toPairs, map, applySpec, head, last, sortBy, descend } = R

const fn = pipe(
  countBy(prop('id')),
  toPairs,
  map(applySpec({
    id: pipe(head, Number), // or just id: head if the id doesn't have to be a number
    count: last,
  })),
  sortBy(descend(prop('count'))), // or ascend
)

const arr = [{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":3,"score":4},{"id":1,"score":3}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats what i want

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `countBy` will be part of the solution, if you're using Ramda.  I would then choose to pipe that to `toPairs` and `zipObj` to get your final results:

```js
const collect = pipe (
  countBy (prop ('id')),
  toPairs,
  map (zipObj (['id', 'count']))
) 

const data = [{id: 1, score: 4}, {id: 2, score: 3}, {id: 1, score: 4}, {id: 2, score: 3}, {id: 3, score: 4},{id: 1, score: 3}]

console .log (collect (data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, countBy, prop, toPairs, map, zipObj} = R             </script>
```

[`zipObj`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) takes an array of property names and an array of values and zips them together into a single object.

Answer (score 0):

With vanillaJS you can simply use reduce and Map

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":1,"score":4},{"id":2,"score":3},{"id":3,"score":4},{"id":1,"score":3}]

const final = [...data.reduce((op,{id,score})=>{
   if(op.has(id)){
    op.set(id, op.get(id)+1)
   } else {
    op.set(id,1)
   }
   return op;
}, new Map()).entries()].map(([id,count])=>({id,count}))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.entries()` explicitly, since it's the default iterator for Map.